# SQL database structure with two changing properties

Tags: sql, relational-database

Let's assume I am building the backend of a university management software.
I have a users table with the following columns:

```
id
name
birthday
last_english_grade
last_it_grade
```

profs table columns:

```
id
name
birthday
```

I'd like to have a third table with which I can determine all professors teaching a student.
So I'd like to assign multiple teachers to each student.
Those Professors may change any time.
New students may be added any time too.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to do this would be to introduce a third *junction* table, which exists mainly to relate users to professors:

```
users_profs (
    user_id,
    prof_id,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, prof_id)
)
```

The primary key of this junction table is the combination of a user and professor ID.  Note that this table is fairly lean, and avoids the problem of repeating metadata for a given user or professor.  Rather, user/professor information remains in your two original tables, and does not get repeated.

Comment: Thanks. How would I manage multiple professors belonging to one student?

Comment: Every unique student-professor relationship gets one entry in the junction table which I suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed looks like a very clean solution!